# D-H parameters for parallel joint axes

Tags: robotic-arm, dh-parameters

If robot has ***parallel joint axes***,the D-H parameters are not unique.So what can we do to deal with this problem? It is very nice for you to answer or recommend some paper and books.
Thank you~

Comment: DH parameters are meant to establish a relationship between two consecutive reference frames and them being similar or unique has no significance. Can you explain what is the exact problem that you are facing?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you meant with parallel joint axes?

Comment: DH is almost never unique, one can find multiple valid DH descriptions for the same structure

Answer (score 1):

This is an overview of the DH Convention, there is a piece where they discuss having parallel joint axis.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuB_7BkYNMk

IMO I believe that it is best to choose your parameters for that axis in the best way to get to the next joint, or one that represents the physical bodies best. If you choose a solution that makes it difficult to make the next set of parameters, you're causing headache for yourself in the future. Let me know if that helps.